# Windows Phone 8 using phonegap

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, cordova-3

I am creating an windows phone 8 app using phonegap but the following method is not working xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined").

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: function getBinary(file){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", file, false);
    if (xhr.overrideMimeType)
    xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
    xhr.send(null);
    return xhr.responseText;
}

Comment: I have created getBinary function for converting image to binary data
in Windows phone 8 phonegap.But it not generating binary data in proper format it showing wrong binary data and not showing any error.

function getBinary(file){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", file, false);
    if (xhr.overrideMimeType)
    xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
    xhr.send(null);
    return xhr.responseText;
}

Comment: I have debug the code and it showing me error

"Object doesn't support property or method 'overrideMimeType'"